# Modify URL GET variable when Go Back Browser button

Tags: javascript, php

I want to modify the variable of the previous URL when you go back or forward in browser.

Previous url:

mysite.com/store.php?code=1101of&action=add

when go back or forward i want to change to:

mysite.com/store.php?code=1101of&action=none

Comment: This is not how web-browsers work.

Comment: @MartinZeitler That is actually how most Single Page App frameworks work (Vue Router, React Router...). The server is setup to send an `index.html` no matter the route, and then, each time we click on a link, JS displays the right content and manipulates the URL without ever loading a new page. They can do this thanks to the History API, which has been available for quite some time. Pretty handy

Comment: @blex Absolutely not ...because they all use hashtag navigation, which means, that the URL requested at the server-side never changes, to begin with. And these URL do not look alike.

Comment: @MartinZeitler _"because they all use hashtag navigation"_ You made me laugh there :) I build SPAs every day, and no, you don't have to use hashes https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: A proper solution would be to use sessions; messing around on the client-side is the joke here; eg. once wrote a questionnaire with variable steps, which enforced that. But with only a few exceptions (where it actually makes sense), this is crappy UX design.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I agree on that point. Here, `action=add` should never have been in the URL in the first place. It should be idempotent. But in other cases, for faster navigation in an SPA, using the History API is great

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using the [History Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState):

```js
// When we leave the page
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
  var loc = window.location;

  // Get the search query, set the action to none
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(loc.search);
  urlParams.set("action", "none");
  
  // Build the new URL
  var url = loc.pathname + '?' + urlParams.toString() + loc.hash;
  
  // Change the browser history
  history.replaceState(null, "", url);
});
```

Comment: thxs Blex, but if i only want to modify "add" without redefining the complete url?

Comment: works perfect in chrome mate! just one thing, in safari osx not.. do you know why?

Comment: It should, it's been supported since [Safari 5 (2010)](https://caniuse.com/#search=replaceState). To debug, try it without the `window.addEventListener("...", function() {` so that it gets executed on page load. [Open your browser's dev console](https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002197259-How-to-Open-the-Developer-Console-in-your-Browser), see if there are any errors, and see if the address in the URL bar changes

Comment: it's strange becuase when i go back in safari the action change to "none", is working fine in the url bar. But the session go back in time.. put the previous total cart value, and if i press two times the same.. products a subtracting instead of simply stay in the previous page

Comment: looks like there is a bug with history.replaceState in safari